# Cannot find method setDisplayUserLogoEnabled(boolean) problem. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, methods

Was given a task to complete and had to run this code to test the program. When I did, I got an error saying this:

[image]

The code I was given to run was this:

```
package com.example.medicalcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUserLogoEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I have tried to search for a solution online but have found nothing to help. I even checked if my Auto-Import option was on and it actually was turned on.
Due to this, I cleaned the build, restarted the project to re-run the program and still got this error. I'm not sure why this auto-import option isn't working but it's not helpful if issues like this keep springing up in the future where I cannot find the library to import for the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for `ActionBar#setDisplayUseLogoEnabled` instead of `ActionBar#setDisplayUserLogoEnabled`.

Comment: I thought it would've been user but trying both your and the one suggested below's solution really turned out to be perfect. Thank you man.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a spelling mistake. If you check the Android documentation on ActionBar [1] there is no method for `setDisplayUserLogoEnabled`. This should be `setDisplayUseLogoEnabled` [2]

[1] https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar
[2] https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar#setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Oh wow, I did not notice the difference, fixed the mistake and ran the program with success. Thank you very much man, appreciate this help